# How to prove that this matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}a^2+b^2 & b^2 & b^2 & ... & b^2 \\ b^2 & a^2+b^2 & b^2 & ... & b^2\\ \vdots & b^2 & \ddots & & b^2 \\ b^2 & \dots &   &  & a^2+b^2 \end{pmatrix}$, where $a,b\ne 0$. How can I be sure that this matrix is positive definite?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that 
$$x^TAx=\sum_{j=1}^n(a^2+b^2)x_j^2+2\sum_{i\lt j\leqslant n}b^2x_ix_j=b^2\left(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\right)^2 +a^2\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2\geqslant a^2\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2 $$
which is positive unless $x=0$. Note that we only have to require that $a\neq 0$, $b$ can be any real number.

Comment: Nice!  ***Endorsed!!!!***

Comment: @Thanks, I had the first expression, but didn't think about that square of the sumation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbf{A}=a^2 \mathbf{I} + b^2 \mathbf{J}$ where $\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix and $\mathbf{J}$ has all ones, $$z^T \mathbf{A} z = z^T(a^2 \mathbf{I} + b^2 \mathbf{J})z = a^2 z^T \mathbf{I} z + b^2 z^T \mathbf{J} z.$$ If $z = (z_1, \ldots, z_n) \neq (0, \ldots, 0)$ then $$z^T I z = z_1^2 + \ldots z_n^2 > 0$$ and $$z^T J z = (z_1 + \ldots + z_n)^2 \ge 0.$$ Therefore $$a^2 z^T \mathbf{I} z + b^2 z^T \mathbf{J} z > 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Take 2*2 matrix which is  in the left ,the top.
Show that it is positive definite.
After that ,use the  induction.

Comment: Yes. but a matrix may have positive determinant and ***not*** be positive definite, e.g. $J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$; then $\det(J) = 1$ but $\langle x, Jx \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^2$.  Dwell on it!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis you're right. Could you please contribute to my question with answer, if possible?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.:  will do!  workin' on it, patience.  ETA maybe 30 minutes . . . Cheers!